# Difference between colon(:) and eqaul to operator(==) - Generic Where Clause : I want Array to conditionally conform to protocol

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, swift5

I need a brief and clear explanation about why this is happening.

I used "Conditionally Conforming to a Protocol" which is introduced in swift documentation ([link](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html))

I want `Array` type to conform to my `Test` Protocol as long as elements in Array conforms to that protocol.

```swift
protocol Test {
    var result : String {get}
}

extension Int: Test {
    var result: String {
        return "int"
    }
}

extension Array: Test where Element: Test {
    var result: String {
        return "array"
    }
}
```

Then, I declared an instance of Array like this.

```swift
let array1 = Array<Test>()

print(array1 is Test) // **false**
```

I thought array1 was supposed to conform `Test` protocol (`true`) , but it was found not.

Then, I tried the following way of extension, and it worked.

```
extension Array: Test where Element == Test {
    var result: String {
        return "array"
    }
}

let array2 = Array<Test>()

print(array2 is Test) // **true**
```

I thought `Array<Test>()` meant "**array that can take elements conforming to `Test` protocol**", so that this a**rray was supposed to conform to same protocol** just like I declared in the first extension.

**Question** 
1. Difference between colon(`:`) and equal-to operator(`==`)
   - `:` means only conforming type / `==` means identical type?
2. Explanation how it works when I declare array instance like `Array<Test>()`

Comment: This is essentially the same issue as in [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33112559/1187415) – In `Array<Test>()` the `Element` type is equal to  `Test`, but does not conform to `Test`.